# How to convert PyDictionary object to list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using PyDictionary for a project but I need to find a way to see if the meaning of the word I am searching up the meaning for contains the word "greeting".

This is my code:

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
from random import randint
def contains_word(s, w):
    return (' ' + w + ' ') in (' ' + s + ' ')
greetings = ["hi", "hello", "hey", "helloo", "hellooo", "greetings", "greeting", "howdy"]
usr_input = input("Input:")
split_input = usr_input.split()
dictionary=PyDictionary(split_input)
dictionarystr = str(dictionary)
if contains_word(dictionarystr, 'greeting'):
    print(greetings[randint(0,8)])
print(contains_word(dictionarystr, 'greeting'))
print(dictionarystr)
```

But it doesnt work. Instead I get false and I look at what the dictionarystr variable is and it says <PyDictionary Object with 1 words>.

Comment: greetings is a package and what is contains_word? what actually do u want? why you convert pydictionary object into list

Comment: Greetings in my code is a list with different ways to greet someone and contains_word is a function that looks if an input contains another input word. Sorry if I forgot to add some code to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if greeting is in the dictionary by doing this :

```
if 'greeting' in dictionary.args:
```

Also if you want the first word in the dictionary as a string you can do

```
dictionarystr = str(dictionary.args[0])
```